# Configuring AAM to use HTTPS caused many services

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis, alternate-access-mapping

I have configured the AAM to use HTTPS. Actual steps I used are:

1. Create Binding in IIS site to use https and selected a wildcard certificate.
2. From Central Administrator, AAM is configured as-

**Public URLs**

```
    URL                               Zone
    http://sharepoint                 Default
    https://subsite.site.com          Internet
```

**Internal URLs**

```
    URL                               Zone
    http://subsite.site.com          Internet
```

This configuration allowed me to redirect users from `http` to `https`

It caused some services like

`Excel Services` -  Unable to open any Excel file, ExcelWebAccess WebParts error etc.

`InfoPath` - Form taking around 4 min to submit data. Once done, workflow does not run at all.

So I removed my all `IIS` and `AAM` configurations (as listed above) but I was unable to open any site now. So I created new Bindings in IIS on port 80 and added host headers `subsite.site.com`.

Now I can access the site and Excel Services are working fine now, but InfoPath form and Workflow errors are not resolved.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone have same issue, this is how I resolved it.

I checked in Services and found
`Service Bus Gateway` and `Service Bus Manager Broker` services were not running.

So, starting these services resolved my error.